# Excel: Pie Chart of a Question with Limited Possible Responses

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I distributed a survey online and received the answers in an Excel spreadsheet. I would like to make a pie chart out of some of the closed option answers. For example, one of the questions was gender. Is there a way I can create a pie chart that shows the percentage of male vs. female?

Given 30 male and 20 female responses, the pie chart would be cut 60/40, with each part appropriately labeled.

EXAMPLE

```
male
male
female
male
female
female
male
male
male
female
```

I would like that to create a pie chart cut 60/40.

Comment: Just to provide some context: What you want is a frequency distribution. While spreadsheets can deliver this with a few extra steps (as detailed in Bavi_H's response), statistics software (spss, sas, etc.) produce these sorts of descriptive statistics at the click of a button. Just something to consider, if you need to do a lot of this sort of work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll first need to count the number of male and female entries, then make a pie chart out of that data.

In OpenOffice.org Calc I was able to use the COUNTIF function to count the entries, then select the counts and make a pie chart from that. It should be similar in Excel.

[image]

Comment: Works in Excel, too (at least 2007).

Answer (score -1):

If you choose your x and y values and create a pie chart using the graph option and selecting pie chart, Excel should do the rest for you.

Comment: Right. I guess the issue is more that there isn't a second set of values.